# Create an QScrollArea attached to a layout with a Table View

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I have a table view that display some SQLite data with a search filter associated to each query. The table view shows a query of the combination of the different filters. The filters are some QLineEdit located on top of the table in a QHBoxLayout. The QLineEdits are automatically resized with the size of the columns.

The problem here comes because the tableview is too big for being showed at once (it has 28 columns), so it has a scrollbar, and then I cannot resize automatically the QLineEdits to the size of the columns, as they are restricted to the size of the window. What I want to do is to create a QScrollArea that involves both the filters and the table, in a way the same scroll bar that moves the QTableView moves also the filter layout with it, which size is not restricted to the size of the window anymore.

I hope I explained myself clearly. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here it is my code at the moment, I've been trying for a while but I didn't find a satisfyings solution, either the size of the filters does not expand or the scroll bar only works for the table but not for the filters:

```
class ManualSearch(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """Table in which the user can search filtering by any of its columns.
    It also allows to open the source document directly."""

    def __init__(self, query, header_names):
        super(ManualSearch, self).__init__()
        # Set up the model view architecture
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        header = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)
        header.setCascadingSectionResizes(True)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.sizeConstraint()

        # Create a combined layout with the filters and the table
        table_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        filter_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.filter_list = []
        # We use a for loop to create the filters and link them
        # to their correspondent columns
        for i in range(len(header_names)):
            filter_i = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            filter_i.textChanged.connect(
                lambda: self.update_query_filter(query)
            )
            header.sectionResized.connect(
                lambda: self.resize(i, filter_i)
            )
            header.geometriesChanged.connect(
                lambda: self.resize(i, filter_i)
            )
            filter_layout.addWidget(filter_i)
            self.filter_list.append(filter_i)

        filter_layout.setContentsMargins(25, 0, 10, 0)
        table_layout.addLayout(filter_layout)
        table_layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.source_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open source document')
        self.source_button.clicked.connect(self.open_source)

        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Light)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setLayout(table_layout)

        main_layout.addLayout(table_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.source_button)

        self.update_query_filter(query)
        set_table_headers(self.model, header_names)

    def resize(self, order, line):
        """Resize the width of the filter line edit to match the width of its
        corresponding column"""
        line.setFixedWidth(self.view.columnWidth(order))
```

Comment: Note that the lambda you're using in the for will never work as expected, because `i` and `filter_i` will always be the last index and the last QLineEdit (look for "python lambda closure").

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it later, but I didn't changed it because I was focusing on fixing the scrollbar thing first, but thank you for telling me!

Comment: Do you know how I can a do a closure here? I tried some ways but it is not working as intented. Thanks!